# How to print a div on a click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printthis

I'm using printThis by Jason day and on its config page it shows that you can trigger the plugin using:

```
$('selector').printThis();
```

Now when I do that I have noticed that this trigger is showing print box on Page load instead of clicking on a button.

How do I use this plugin and trigger it on a button instead of a default page load?

Usage: https://jasonday.github.io/printThis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to do that you need to add some listener for the `click` event of your button.

Assume this is your HTML:

```
<button id="myButton">Button</button>

<div id="myPrintableContent">
  Some content to print
</div>
```

And this is your javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myPrintableContent').printThis();
  });
});
```

Comment: How will I define this onclick to the button? <button type="button" onclick="yourButtonSelector">Button</button>??

Comment: Thanks, it did work. Can you also tell me why it's cutting of content? Example, https://prnt.sc/s1g21f

Comment: @Robinhood you should provide a real executable example in order to ask for such help.  showing screenshots only is not really helpful.